# Usage of different Python API/functions to operate on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, kubernetes

I can't figure out which functions exist in Kubernetes Python Client library or some other python library that is related to Kubernetes. I have been able to figure out functions like bind() which binds some pod to a node, and some functions which describe resource usage of pods and nodes. Which other functions does this library or any similar library offer?

Comment: Functions of _what_? What library are you using? You'd use placement selectors / affinity to bind pods to nodes... Not sure how that is Python specific

Comment: Sorry, for the unclear question earlier. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Kubernetes official Python client: [kubernetes-client/python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

Check the [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples) folder to see different operations on Kubernetes using this client.

Comment: I went through this github link but the functions are not properly defined. Moreover, I think all the api/functions are not covered in the examples.

Comment: You should not expect all the API to be covered in the example. Go through the files in [kubernetes/client/api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes/client/api) to find out the available functions.